# Multiple selected options when select emptied and repopulated with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently upgraded to Chrome 38 and I've observed strange behavior. When emptying a `<select>` containing 2 `<option>`, both of them seem selected afterwards. When re-appending the options to the original select, the value of the select is different than in the beginning.

Here's the code (this strange behaviour occurs on Chrome 38 and Firefox 32; on Chrome 37 it worked fine, i.e. only the first option had `selected` attribute `true` and `select.val()` yielded `1`):

```
var select = $('<select>');
var option1 = $('<option value="1" selected>opt1</option>').appendTo(select);
var option2 = $('<option value="2">opt2</option>').appendTo(select);

$.merge(option1, option2);
select.empty();
// Both are selected.
option1.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.selected);
});
select.append(option1);
// The second one is considered to be "really" selected.
console.log(select.val());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uvrt38k/1/)

What I want to achieve in the end is (stable) sort the `<option>`s based on an arbitrary comparison function.

Comment: What is `$.merge(option1, option2)` supposed to do? `$.merge` is supposed to be used with arrays, not jQuery objects.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `select.empty()` seems to be the culprit. When the options become disconnected from the select, they both become selected.

Comment: Selection isn't really a property of an option. It's actually a property of the select. It has a `selectedIndex` property that indicates which of its options is selected. Asking whether an option is selected is really asking whether its index in the containing select is equal to its selectedIndex. When the options become disconnected, this is meaningless.

Comment: When I use `option1 = option1.add(option2);` instead of `$.merge(option1, option2)`, the result is the same.
If selection isn't a property of an option, why does the value in the end is `2`, instead of `1`?

Comment: My guess is because it's added to the selection last.